# "git add ." not working

Tags: windows, git

In a folder in my project I am trying "git add images" (images is a folder). Nothing happens. I also went into the images and ran "git add ." and nothing happened.

In both cases "git status" tells me my branch is up to date.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Is it being ignored by `gitignore`?

Comment: @17slim - I don't think so. How can I test that?

Comment: Were the files already added?

Comment: In your repo directory, look at the .gitignore file and see if any of the rules there might match your folder. If so, remove/modify them so they don't.

Comment: Oh, and if it's empty it might lead to issues as well. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932982/3927528) maybe add a .gitignore for now. (if you plan to put things in it, just leave the file empty and it might work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if `images/` is an *empty* folder, Git would not add it: it adds only files.
Adding just a folder requires indeed adding a file, like a `.keep`, or a `.gitignore` if you don't want to track its content.

Second, if `images/` is a folder with files, and those files are not added, pick one of those untracked file (that you cannot add), and type:

```
git check-ignore -v -- images/afile
```

That way, you won't have to check all `.gitignore` files: Git will do that for you, and print any `.gitignore` path (and the rule in it) which is responsible for `images/` content (the files) to be ignored (you would need to do `git add -f` to force them to be added)